# cannot find VehicleObstacleControl module -- in module (veins::PhyLayer80211p)

Tags: veins

I have encountered a critical issue in veins-5.2 simulation in the vehicle obstacle shadowing model as follows.

```
**initializeVehicleObstacleShadowing(): cannot find VehicleObstacleControl module -- in module (veins::PhyLayer80211p)
RSUExampleScenario.rsu[0].nic.phy80211p (id=11), during network initialization**
```

However, I can find VehicleObstacleControl module in the veins::PhyLayer80211p.cc as follows.

```
**unique_ptr<AnalogueModel> PhyLayer80211p::initializeVehicleObstacleShadowing(ParameterMap& params)
{
    // init with default value
    bool useTorus = world->useTorus();
    const Coord& playgroundSize = *(world->getPgs());
    ParameterMap::iterator it;
    VehicleObstacleControl* vehicleObstacleControlP = VehicleObstacleControlAccess().getIfExists();
    if (!vehicleObstacleControlP) throw cRuntimeError("initializeVehicleObstacleShadowing(): cannot find VehicleObstacleControl module");
    return make_unique<VehicleObstacleShadowing>(this, *vehicleObstacleControlP, useTorus, playgroundSize);
}**
```

I highly appreciate if you could provide me with some guidance so that I can resolve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

BR.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the exactly same issue here. This error can be traced back to PhyLayer80211p.cc and VehicleObstacleControl.h within Veins, and further into OMNet++ files like csimulation.h and cmodule.h. It seems that the wanted scenario just could not find the path of *vehicleObstacles* (however, for the SimpleObstacleShadowing model, the scenario could find the path of *obstacles*), which is extremely confusing.

**Solved already. In the OMNet++ world, just do not forget about those .ned files. Some modifications needs to be done in the scenario.ned file.**